# Null Pointer Exception in mapreduce and GlobStatus

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

I recently came across an issue when using Hadoop FileSystem API and GlobStatus while writing Mapreduce application.

Here's snippet of the driver program.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), conf);
Path path = new Path(args[0] + args[1]);

FileStatus[] status = fs.globStatus(path);
Path[] paths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);
```

and here is how I invoke the program

> yarn jar MyMapReduceTest01.jar com.abc.test.MyMapRedTestDriver /user/root/raw_data/ abc*

This results in the following exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.abc.test.MyMapRedTestDriver.run(MyMapRedTestDriver.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.abc.test.MyMapRedTestDriver.main(MyMapRedTestDriver.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The files in the /user/root/raw_data/ directory are named as 
abc_01.txt
abc_02.txt
...

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a problem in the way the globstatus is handled in the Hadoop filesystem API.

To make the above program work without any code change I just needed to change the command to

> yarn jar MyMapReduceTest01.jar com.abc.test.MyMapRedTestDriver /user/root/raw_data/ **abc_***